# Cannot start nuxt: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sitemap')

Tags: nuxt.js, seo, sitemap

I'm working on my first nuxt js project and I've a small problem. I installed a sitemap in my project using "npm install @nuxtjs/sitemap" and I've an error that I don't know how to fix.

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^3.3.3",
    "nuxt-simple-sitemap": "^2.4.8",
    "sitemap": "^7.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.4",
    "@nuxtjs/sitemap": "^2.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.1.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1"
  }
}
```

nuxt.config.ts

```js
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
        
        '@nuxtjs/sitemap',
    ],
})
```

This is the error I've when I try to run the project
[image]

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

@nuxtjs/sitemap is no longer compatible with Nuxt3.

### For a simple static website

You can quickly generate your sitemap using the new `simple-sitemap` module for Nuxt3. [You can follow their instructions here](https://nuxt.com/modules/simple-sitemap).

### If you have dynamic routes (as /blog/[slug].vue)

You can generate your sitemap.xml using only the sitemapJS plugin.

```
npm install --save-dev sitemap
```

Add these lines of code in your nuxt.config

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // ...
  nitro: {
    prerender: {
      routes: ['/sitemap.xml']
    }
  }
})
```

Now you have to create a file to execute when you run the nuxi generate / build. Name that file `sitemap.xml.ts` inside the directory `/server/routes/`.

Inside the file, you just created you have to write [this code snippet](https://github.com/benoitdemaegdt/nuxt3-sitemap/blob/main/sitemap.xml.ts) in order to generate the dynamic routes.

Comment: Dynamic routes of this package does not work. There is not code inside sitemap.xml.ts file that generates dynamic URL